# User Session using different languages and MVVM

Tags: c#, session, mvvm

I am writing a **desktop application** using MVVM and Prism and I have the following problem. As well as the labels etc it is also necessary to store data in different languages.

For example, in the USA a user might be able to login using either English or Spanish (as they are a native speaker).

- If the user logs in using Spanish when they go into a product details
  form the product description will be saved to the database against
  the Spanish language.
- If they log in using English the product description will be saved to
  the database and related to the English language.

At the moment my only ideas is as below:-
 - a globally accessible ApplicationViewModel that contains a
   CurrentLoggedInUser property

What I would like to know is how I go about saving the currently logged in user's chosen language when using MVVM, particularly in a desktop application? 
*N.B the chosen language can be different to the language and locale that the operating system is in*
How do other people go about resolving this and maintaining the user's "session" across different windows / user controls when using MVVM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is store the current language somewhere, maybe as an [LCID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.lcid.aspx).

Generally this is used to load a language specific resource file, which takes care of most language dependant situations. Controls etc just store all their strings in resources, so they don't need direct access to the current language.

For situations where you do need access to the language, such as knowing where to save your database string, then yes, the language should be exposed either as some static/singleton, or  more desirably, should be injected into whatever ViewModels need it.

Comment: An LCID will be ideal for the language to show localised resources but for this question I was more interested about how to get the Currently Logged in user's context into the viewmodel. Are you suggesting that this could be done by injecting something like an IUserContext into each and every viewmodel that needs to use the language property? Thanks Alex

Comment: That would be my preferred way yes. If the ViewModel needs the information then it needs to get it from somewhere. Yes, you could have a static service if you think injecting is going to be impractical, but injecting is far preferable to allow things like unit testing.

Comment: Meant to say, if the ViewModel only needs the language, then only inject the language to prevent unnecessarily coupling it with your IUserContext. If it needs other stuff in the user context then obviously inject the entire context.